# Amend autosuspension of deleted accounts to include recreation for Sockpuppet deletions?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, account-suspension, deleted-accounts

> Related: [Automatically suspend accounts recreated after a moderator deleted the original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277230/automatically-suspend-accounts-recreated-after-a-moderator-deleted-the-original)

Recently downstream on Ask Ubuntu, an account was deleted for being a sockpuppet of another account.

Within an hour afterwards, they were able to create a *new* Ask Ubuntu user account with the exact same StackExchange Network account but did not get suspended or autodeleted.

**This seems to be a flaw in the 'automatically suspend' function**, as *technically* deletion as a sockpuppet should be considered the same as 'no longer welcome' (note that I deleted this specific case's second account as "no longer welcome" with the description of the sockpuppetry in the delete reason).

**Can said auto-suspension function be amended to include Sockpuppet deletions of user accounts as well?**

---

EDIT: Noticed that the deletes for "This user was created to circumvent system or moderator imposed restrictions and continues to contribute poorly" are also not included.  I think the autosuspend system needs to be included here as well because this is essentially the same as "no longer welcome"...

Comment: The automatic suspension only kicks in if the account is either destroyed for spam, or deleted using the "no longer welcome" option (for context to others).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog ... which is why I included the 'related' post link.  But it should be expanded to include the additional delete reason of sockpuppet deletion, in my opinion